# iFrame URL pamameters in UIWebView not works

Tags: ios, objective-c, iframe, uiwebview

The parameters of the url do not work in my uiwebview

But it works very well elsewhere

```
NSString *identifierTest = @"x5b4cfz";

NSString *Str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<iframe frameborder=\"0\" width=\"%@\" height=\"200\" src=\"//www.dailymotion.com/embed/video/%@?ui-start-screen-info=0\" allowfullscreen></iframe>",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%f",self.webView.frame.size.width - 15], identifierTest];

[_webView loadData:[Str dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]
                      MIMEType:@"text/html" textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
                       baseURL:[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.dailymotion.com"]];
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you added transport security?

Comment: @DSDharma Yes of course

Comment: @victorbill i have getting this in console iFrameWebViewQuestionObjc[595:113663] [] __tcp_connection_write_eof_block_invoke Write close callback received error: [22] Invalid argument